# Can Polish Citizen Enter Ukraine With ID?

Tags: passports, ukraine, polish-citizens

Can a Polish citizen enter Ukraine only with ID? (without passport)
I am interested in both cases: as a transit flight with change in Kiev (to stay only within the airport) and if it's possible to spend a few hours in the city, outside the airport?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All EU citizens are allowed to enter Ukraine without visa and Poland is not an exclusion. However, you **cannot** use ID-card for crossing the border, as stated [here](http://dpsu.gov.ua/en/activities/skipping/skipping_14.htm) ([Ukrainian version](http://dpsu.gov.ua/ua/activities/skipping/skipping_3.htm)) by the State Border Guard Service.
I am almost sure that you won't be able to make a transit (or airport transfer) with ID as well.

> Documents required for crossing the state border of Ukraine:
>
> - Foreign passport;
> - [...]
>
> **Attention! ID-card, which identifies the personality, gives no right  to cross the State Border of Ukraine**

Comment: Almost right. You can change planes without clearing immigration on an ID Card IF the destination country accepts it for entry

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **enter** Ukraine, but you can change planes at Kiev-Boryspil airport.

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PL&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=UA&selTrans=Ukraine&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> Transit refused to nationals of Poland with a national ID
>     card.
>
> Except when transiting through Kiev Boryspil (KBP) on
>      Ukraine International Airlines (PS).

At the entry to transit security control, a border officer will check your boarding pass and ID card

Comment: Your bio could more accurately say "Mostly specialised in performing Timatic searches."

Comment: @fkraiem Haha xD Can't help the fact that Timatic's usually the most reliable source, now can I? I also have a contact in the Timatic team, whom I message when it's clear there's an error